# libs3 multipart upload

Tags: amazon-s3

i am using libs3 for storing files on S3 from my C++ project. I came across an article which says that amazon supports multipart upload on S3. But I am not able to find this feature in libs3.

Can any one help.

Answer (score 2):

As of March 18, 2013 their TODO file indicates that multi-part uploads are not yet supported.